# python setup.py install Fails when trying to install Xgboost on Win 64 bit

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, xgboost

I have tried ot install xgBoost on Windows 8.1 64 Bit with Python 3.7 Pip the usual way, it failed with error. I then tried with Pip3, same error.
I then tried to install by trying to first downloading Wheels from [Here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost)
and [Also this](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html), The Wheels were Not correct for my platform(it appears). Then, I tried my best to follow steps on the Kaggle site : https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/31960. (Using **Git Bash**). 
 When that failed.
I managed to download the Tar pkg on my local PC, and tried to run the install I tried to run an install: python setup.py install

I was stuck on the following error:

> INFO:XGBoost build_ext:Building from source.
> C:\Users[**myUName]\Downloads\xgboost\lib\xgboost.dll INFO:XGBoost
> build_ext:Run CMake command: ['cmake', 'xgboost', '-GVisual Studio 16
> 2019', '-DUSE_OPENMP=1', '-DUSE_CUDA=0', '-DUSE_NCCL=0',
> '-DBUILD_WITH_SHARED_NCCL=0', '-DHIDE_CXX_SYMBOLS=1', '-DUSE_HDFS=0',
> '-DUSE_AZURE=0', '-DUSE_S3=0',  '-DPLUGIN_LZ4=0',
> '-DPLUGIN_DENSE_PARSER=0']  **error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find
> the file specified**

Need help specific to my platform, TIA to all.

Comment: Additional Details: ERROR: xgboost-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: I also tried to update Pip Version, No Luck

Comment: It's possible that I am missing some dependancy, it's just that I don't know what it is yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following command.

```
pip install pipwin
```

and then

```
pipwin install xgBoost
```

Comment: I am trying to follow up, did this solve your issue, or did it not help you at all?

Comment: it did Solve.. I couldn't thank you Enough CForce...